# Pass down prop when it has resolved Vue firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem where I want to pass down firebase user down as a prop from root component, down to my child components. I succeeded this step by passing the user to my router.
However, the problem is that I wrap my new Vue instance in onAuthStateChange listener.

```
const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App :user="user" />',
    components: { App },
    data() {
      return {
        user: {
          email: user.email,
          uid: user.uid,
          capital: findUserById(user.uid),
        },
      };
    },
  });
  //remove this listener so that we aren't trying to make new vue objects
  //every time the auth state changes.
  unsubscribe();
});
```

findUserById returns user by id as expected. However it is being ran after the Vue component has been created and that causes capital to be undefined.

```
const findUserById = id => {
  db
    .ref()
    .child('users/')
    .orderByChild('uid')
    .equalTo(id)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
      const obj = snap.val();
      return obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].capital;
    });
};
```

Any solution to this? I tried updating the prop in mounted lifecycle, still no luck.
[image: no luck]

My app component is just a Vue Router

Comment: You never return something from your `findUserById `, and that is why its undefined

Comment: As Ferrybig says, your `return` statement actually returns from `function(snap) {` and not from `findUserById`. The data is being loaded from Firebase asynchronously, and there's no way to return it from `findUserById`. For a longer explanation, see Doug's excellent blog post here: https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. So if I understand correctly, I cannot return resolved promise in my helper function? Then the only thing I can do is return a promise, and then resolve it in my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by returning a promise in my helper function

```
export function findUserById(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db
      .ref()
      .child('users/')
      .orderByChild('uid')
      .equalTo(id)
      .on('value', snap => {
        const obj = snap.val();
        resolve(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]);
      });
  });
}
```

And since Vue can react to changes when you are using computed properties I used that to await the result of the helper function returned promise.
However it was not that pleasant experience doing that, so I used a helper Vue library especially suited for these kind of things - https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed
Then I was able to do something like this:

```
asyncComputed: {
      async user() {
        return await findUserById(user.uid);
      },
    },
```